# The Debezium Kafka based KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS property setting is ignored

Tags: docker-compose, kafka

I have a Docker Compose based Swarm with a Zookeeper service that starts fine, but the Kafka service cannot start.

It keeps using the default `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` property:

```
debezium_kafka.1.5hhrqfp5kqts@stephane-pc    | Using ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
debezium_kafka.1.5hhrqfp5kqts@stephane-pc    | Using KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://10.0.83.239:9092
```

And of course it cannot find the listeners specified in the map:

```
debezium_kafka.1.5hhrqfp5kqts@stephane-pc    | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: inter.broker.listener.name must be a listener name defined in advertised.listeners. The valid options based on currently configured listeners are PLAINTEXT
```

My `docker-compose-dev.yml` file contains:

```
  kafka:
    image: debezium/kafka:1.2
    deploy:
      mode: global
    ports:
      - "9094:9094"
      - "9095:9095"
    networks:
      common:
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/debezium/volumes/kafka/data:/kafka/data"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/debezium/volumes/kafka/logs:/kafka/logs"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: FROM_DOCKER_NETWORK://kafka:9092,FROM_HOST://kafka:9094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: FROM_DOCKER_NETWORK://kafka:9092,FROM_HOST://localhost:9094
      KAFKA_ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,FROM_DOCKER_NETWORK:PLAINTEXT,FROM_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: FROM_DOCKER_NETWORK
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something wrong, by specifying an hard coded hostname in the `KAFKA_LISTENERS` property:

```
KAFKA_LISTENERS: FROM_DOCKER_NETWORK://kafka:9092,FROM_HOST://kafka:9094
```

After replacing the `kafka` hostname by the `0.0.0.0` IP address, as in:

```
KAFKA_LISTENERS: FROM_DOCKER_NETWORK://0.0.0.0:9092,FROM_HOST://0.0.0.0:9094
```

the issue was gone and the Kafka service could start.

Note that the advertised listeners keep the container name for accessing the Kafka service from another container, and the `localhost` name for accessing the Kafka service from the Docker host:

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: FROM_DOCKER_NETWORK://kafka:9092,FROM_HOST://localhost:9094
```

As explained [in this tutorial](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/) the `0.0.0.0` value means the listener is listening on all interfaces. And [this tutorial](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/) says subtly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

@stephane Thanks a lot.

I could not use kafka as the name, but had to bind it to the IP address (from docker network) and it worked.